# Ayuda Consulta SQL Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sql

Estoy utilizando el `schema HR de SQL developer`.

Usando el ejemplo anterior visualizar también el nombre de la ciudad
añadiendo una nueva tabla `LOCATIONS`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para intentar resolver este ejercicio realice lo siguiente:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_NAME,CITY  
FROM COUNTRIES  
NATURAL JOIN REGIONS  
NATURAL JOIN LOCATIONS   
ORDER BY REGION_ID ASC,COUNTRY_ID DESC, CITY DESC;
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no me muestra la columna `CITY` exacamente como se muestra en la primer imagen.

El primer ejercicio es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el cual ya resolví con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME,REGION_NAME  
FROM COUNTRIES  
NATURAL JOIN REGIONS;
```

Comment: No queda claro cual es tu problema. Explica por que no se muestra  exactamente como en la imagen el campo CITY.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que _te muestra_ la consulta que tienes?

Comment: Perdon, corregi la primera imagen y añadi el resultado que me muestra la consulta

Comment: No sal eigual por el orden en que se muestran los registros (a partir de las ciudades de USA empiezan a variar). Al hacer el ORDER BY por city, utilza el nombre para ordenar alfabeticamente, ¿Tal vez hay alguna columna adicional en la tabla donde esta CITY y ordena por esa, si no la hay es porque tal vez no es relevante para el problema (y por lo tanto tu respuesta, aunque con un orden diferente, está bien).